# Check a property of the General Linear Group ${\rm GL}(2,\mathbb{F}_3)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am manually finding all conjugate subgroups of ${\rm GL}(2,\mathbb{F}_3).$ I want to check which subgroups have this property $HH^g=H^gH,\forall g\in {\rm GL}(2,\mathbb{F}_3).$ However, I still can't check it all by hand. I know there is GAP system that can do calculations but I don't know how to use it and am learning to use it.

Please see if this property holds true for this group ${\rm GL}(2,\mathbb{F}_3)$ for its subgroups or guide me in a better approach
. Furthermore, I want to check this out for ${\rm GL}(2,\mathbb{F}_4).$ Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I am myself learning the subject right now. Could you once mention what $H$ denotes; is it an element of $GL(2,\mathbb{F}_3)$? And what is represented by the superscript notation $H^g$? Maybe I could try my hand at it then.

Comment: Conjugate permutable subgroups (subgroups that have the property you are seeking) are necessarily subnormal. Can you identify the subnormal subgroups of $\operatorname{GL}_2(3)$?

Comment: ${\rm GL}(2,4)$ is actually easier, because it is isomorphic to $C_3 \times A_5$ and has only the obvious subnormal subgroups, all of which are normal. ${\rm GL}(2,3)$ has some subnormal subgroups that are not normal.